# What does the windows internet pipeline look like?

Tags: networking

I've had the strangest problem for years now, I cant visit some internet sites. Doesn't sound too weird but the weird part is - there appears to be no reason why.

When I try to ping those sites, it says "general failure". When I try and telnet to those sites it says "connection failed", It's not even trying. The problem is constrained to this windows installation (i tried a live linux dvd), other user accounts included.
If memory serves - heres what I've tried

1. Dozens of virus/malware scans provided by all the major vendors - nothing found
2. Various browsers - no difference
3. Different DNS as well as flushing DNS cache - the ip's provided are correct anyways
4. Checked out the hosts file - nothing there
5. Fiddling with the MTU as well as other networking settings available in tcp optimizer - no effect
6. Connecting through a proxy - they work through a proxy
7. Made sure there is no firewall blockage by either this computer, the router or by my isp
8. Verified all windows files - no corruption
9. Tried different drivers for the NIC - no effect
10. Tried different NIC - no effect
11. Observed system level packets through wireshark - first theres the dns query which works fine and then just nothing, the packet never gets sent
12. Hooked my browsers winsock to monitor packets - when connecting to other sites I see traffic as expected, when trying to go to one of the non responsive sites the packet never gets sent.

Some addresses that don't work - anything in microsofts servers, ucla.edu, samsung.com. Other than that the computer and rest of the internet works perfectly fine.

So.. the problem must be somewhere between the packet entering winsock and the NIC driver getting the command. Does anybody know what kind of pipeline is between those 2? And how to test it?

I know.. easiest fix would be to just reinstall windows but I see this as a quest! Must figure out whats going on.

EDIT: I tried tracing the packet through windows dll's and the journey ends with system error 11050 in DnsApi which is strange since I pinged with the ip address so in theory it shouldn't even need the dns..? Also - forgot to mention, dealing with win 7 here with all the latest updates.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735804(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting TCP/IP (assuming Windows 7)

- open a command prompt, click Start and then type cmd in the Search programs and files box.
- Under Programs, right-click the CMD.exe icon, and then click Run as administrator.
- When the User Account Control box appears, click Yes.
- At the command prompt, enter the following command, and then press Enter:
- netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

Note If you don't want to specify a directory path for the log file, run the following command instead: `netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt`

- Restart the computer.

Comment: forgot to mention - tried that too